# draggable without jquery ui: how to stop dragging the not-draggable and type-able elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this draggable code without jquery ui and I want to modify it to suit my requirements:

1. I don't want `<p>` tag or any inside `<div>` tag to be draggable.
2. I need to be able to type in the input fields.

html,

```
<div>
    <p>not draggable</p>
    <input type="text" value="type-able"/>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

I tried with these below but they don't work,

```
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

jquery,

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('mousedown', 'div', function(e) {
        $(this).addClass('draggable').parents().on('mousemove', function(e) {

            $('.draggable').offset({
                top: e.pageY - $('.draggable').outerHeight() / 2,
                left: e.pageX - $('.draggable').outerWidth() / 2
            }).on('mouseup', function() {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }).on('mouseup', function() {
        $('.draggable').removeClass('draggable');
    });
});
```

any idea how I can do that?

css,

```
body {padding:50px;}

div {
  cursor:move;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  background-color:black;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:2px;
  float:left;
}

.draggable {
  background-color:yellow;
}

p {
    border:1px solid red;
    background:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert something like this right at the top of your drag function :

```
if(e.target.className == "dontDragMePlease") return;
```

Then add

```
classname="dontDragmePlease"
```

to every element you don't want to drag with that function.

Or:

```
if(e.target.tagName == 'INPUT') return;
```

Like this:

```
$('body').on('mousedown', 'div', function(e) {
 if(e.target.className == "dontDragMePlease") return;
 if(e.target.tagName == 'INPUT') return;
    $(this).addClass('draggable').parents().on('mousemove', function(e) {
```